# Some bullets doesn't show in multiplayer mode

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm developing a shooting game in Unity and I have a problem with multiplayer mode when using Unity Multiplayer Platform(Unity Servers). My bullets are using Network Identity and Network Transform.
Some bullets doesn't show up on the side that shoots them but they are visible in other side and the damage is taken.
Here's my shooting script:

```
     [Command]
     public void CmdShoot(){
         this.transform.FindChild("gun").SendMessage ("CmdGunshoot");
     }
```

Here's my gun script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class shoot : NetworkBehaviour {
     public GameObject bulletPref;
     public int power;
     private Transform spawner;
     public int damage;

     void Start () {
         spawner = this.transform.FindChild("Bspwaner");
     }

     [Command]
     public void CmdGunshoot (){
         GameObject bull = Instantiate(bulletPref, spawner.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
         bull.GetComponent<bullet>().dmg = damage;
         bull.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(spawner.right * power);
         NetworkServer.Spawn (bull);
         Destroy(bull, 2.0f);
     }
 }
```

Here's my bullet script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class bullet : NetworkBehaviour {

    public GameObject ie;
    public int dmg;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
        Instantiate(ie, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        NetworkServer.Destroy (this.gameObject);
        if (other.gameObject.tag != "Player")
            return;
        other.gameObject.SendMessage ("takeDamage", dmg);
    }
}
```

What the problem can be?

Thanks in advance,